# TAG 216 PWD_AUTH command Fails after set password with NFC Tols

Tags: android, nfc, password-protection

I am able to write in TAG 216 using password protection. And I am able to autenticate using my own app.

The problem comes  when I put password protection in a tag using external tool as "NFC Tool" and in a second step try to rewrite the tag with my app.

When I try :

```
response = ndef.transceive(new byte[]{
                            Constants.PWD_COMMNAND, // PWD_AUTH
                            pass[0], pass[1] , pass[2], pass[3]
                    });
```

I get an java.io.IOException: Transceive failed.

Nevertheless, If I write my own password in this way:

`response = ndef.transceive(new byte[]{
                            Constants.WRITE_COMMNAND, // WRITE
                            PWD_PAG,   // page address
                            pass[0] , pass[1] , pass[2] , pass[3]

                    });`

Then the PWD_AUTH command doesn't fail and i am able to write in tag.

Seems that the NFC Tools store the password in diferent way.

I get the bytes of the password in this way:

```
byte[] pass =password.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Maybe some mask is needed in order to write the password? When I write the password "1111" The log of:

```
byte[] pass =password.getBytes("UTF-8");
Log.d(TAG,"Password ("+pass[0]+","+ pass[1] +","+ pass[2] +","+ pass[3] +")
```

Is : Password (49,49,49,49)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I can confirm that NFC Tools convert the password into 4 bytes with a MD5 operation.

Thanks to the people of https://www.wakdev.com/

Comment: md5 produces a 128-bit digest. How can you use it as pwd which has only 4 bytes?